# Getting same output dimension from the fimplicit matlab function

Tags: matlab

I am using `fimplicit` function to plot two implicit curves as follows:

```
Limit=[ 0 1.5 0 15];
MDensity=1000;
Exactcurve=fimplicit(f,Limit,'MeshDensity',MDensity);
hold on
Aproxcurve=fimplicit(faprox,Limit,'--','MeshDensity',MDensity);
```

and the output can be seen in the attached figure.
[image]

Now I wanna measure the error between the two curves, I tried the following:

```
RMSE=norm(Aproxcurve.YData-Exactcurve.YData)
```

But I get error as `Aproxcurve.YData` and `Exactcurve.YData` have different dimensions! I am wondering why the outputs of the two implicit curves have different dimensions despite they have the same limit interval and MeshDensity? Even when I remove the limit and the MeshDensity and leave it in the default setting I get the same error.